# Windows not reading .py file correctly

Tags: python, linux, windows, character-encoding

Hi, I have made a simple Tkinter program in Python 2.7, I typed up this script on a Linux Distro. When I execute the file on Windows 10 it can’t parse the file properly.

Here’s the script:

```
# Demo Program
def hi():
    print("Hello!")
# end  of function
hi() # call function
```

But the. It ends up like this on Windows:

```
# Demo Programdef hi():    print("Hello")# end of functionhi() # call function
```

I’m not sure if it’s soemthing to do with the encoding, the file that I wrote on my linux distro saved it in the UTF-8 format. When I type a text document on Windows it saves it in the ANSI encoding format.

Overall, when I try and read the file it appears in a piece of junk that isn’t understandable. Even when I execute it in python on Windows it can’t read the file.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does python produce a specific error message?

Comment: Basically, python.exe can’t read the file on a Windows System but it can on a Linux system, this question allready has the purfect answer though

Comment: Python should be able to handle \n newlines on windows. Again, does python produce a specific error message?

Comment: Not realy, it just says about the typical “this makes no sense to me” error messages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's due to the difference in line endings between Linux and Windows. In Linux, the end of a line is marked by a `\n` character, while in Windows, it is two characters: `\r\n`. The python script should work fine (The interpreter will see `\n` and be happy), but it will look a little weird if you are using the default notepad.exe to write your python script. I would recommend IDLE, which comes with Python and works a charm with both line endings.

Comment: Does this mean at the line of a python program I can put \n and it’ll work fine?

Comment: "All of these forms can be used equally, regardless of platform." https://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#physical-lines

Comment: @AwesomeMinecraft pretty much just don't use notepad and everything will be fine. Notepad will destroy the line endings as soon as you save the file - it isn't made for files from Linux. If you take a .py file straight from Linux, it will still run on Windows (As long as you don't edit it in notepad) because the `\n` characters are still there.